# Outliers and Data Analysis

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, dataset, outliers, error

I have data for gamma-ray bursts. They follow more or less an exponential model. I tried to first fit it with a constant to get rid of invalid plots and which do not show any model. From the remaining plots, I also want to remove points that are invalid or points which are insignificant(Outliers you can say). I plotted a residual plot for the same which shows the contribution of each data point to the chi-square. I want to know is there any way in the chi-square contribution part where I can n=knoiw which points are outliers to this data set(by looking at the chi-square contribution)? Any other suggestions are welcomed.[image: Gamma-Ray Pulse]

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of these points? Because they aren't consistent with your model?

Comment: I want to remove point such points which contribute too much to the chisq. They are mostly sudden dips in the data